# Can I come to Canada 6 months before my college starts and get work here?

Tags: canada, study

My flights got cancelled due to Covid-19 and I am thinking to defer classes to September intake.
I want to fly as soon as flights open before it gets banned again.

Comment: Can you clarify but editing in your nationality and what you mean by work, do you mean employment with a Canadian employer? This may be more suitable for our Expatriates site.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not a Canadian citizen or permanent resident, and do not otherwise have a valid work permit, it is not possible for you to work.

As a full-time student you may be eligible to work on- or off-campus under conditions. But in any case, [you may not work in Canada until you start your studies](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/study-canada/work/work-on-campus.html) (i.e. after the semester starts).